# JavaFX 8 Stacked Bar Chart numerical sorting issue

Tags: java, sorting, javafx

I'm developing an application that parses a text file and looks for times between certain sent actions, a simple visual aid in short.

My issue is that the sorting on the StackedBarCharts x-axis has gone awry, as shown by the image linked below;

[Image of sorting issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVcAH.png)

The relevant code for generating these charts;

```
public boolean updateBarChart(Tab t, DataHolder dock) {
    Node n = t.getContent();
    Node graph = n.lookup("#Graph");
    StackedBarChart bc = (StackedBarChart) graph;


    //Barchart
    NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    bc.setTitle("Summary");
    bc.getData().clear();
    bc.setLegendVisible(true);
    bc.setCategoryGap(1);

    xAxis.setTickLabelRotation(90);

    ArrayList<String> tempArr = dock.getUniqueActionNumbers();

    for(String s : tempArr)
    {
        bc.getData().add(dock.calculateIntervalsBetweenActions(s));

    }

    bc.getXAxis().setAutoRanging(true);
    bc.getYAxis().setAutoRanging(true);

    return true;
}
```

The code generating the series, where:

ConstantStrings are an ENUM of the constantly reocurring strings,

PairValue is a simple home brewed Pair made for a simple local caching system so I don't have search the entire data structure every time I want each instance of a specific value.

```
public XYChart.Series<String, Number> calculateIntervalsBetweenActions(String actionNumber)
{
    XYChart.Series returnValue = new XYChart.Series();
    returnValue.setName(actionNumber);
    LocalTime lastTime = null;
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> listOfNumbers = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int maxVal = 0;

    ArrayList<PairValue> temp = metaMap.get(ConstantStrings.RECIEVED_ACTION_NUMBER);

    if (temp != null)
    {
        for( PairValue p : temp)
        {
            String s = dp.get(p.getNodePlace()).getTokens().get(p.getPointPlace()).getValue();
            if (!s.equals(actionNumber))
                continue;

            if(lastTime != null)
            {
                LocalTime tempTime = LocalTime.parse(dp.get(p.getNodePlace()).getTimestamp());
                int seconds = (int) lastTime.until(tempTime, SECONDS);
                if(seconds > maxVal) maxVal = seconds;

                Integer count = listOfNumbers.get(seconds);
                listOfNumbers.put(seconds, (count == null) ? 1 : count + 1);
                lastTime = tempTime;


            }
            else lastTime = LocalTime.parse(dp.get(p.getNodePlace()).getTimestamp());

        }
        //todo add filter so the user can choose what to ignore and not.
        for(int i = 2; i <= maxVal; i++) {
            Integer find = listOfNumbers.get(i);
            if(find != null) {

                XYChart.Data toAdd = new XYChart.Data(Integer.valueOf(i).toString(), find);
                returnValue.getData().add(toAdd);


            }

        }

    }
    else Logger.getGlobal().warning("Could not find meta map for Recieved action numer, aborting");

    return returnValue;
}
```

My suspicions lie in the order the Series are added, but that should not matter in my opinion, so my question stands; Is there any simple way to sort these values properly?

Comment: Make sure your series is right. What does next code print before `return` command: `for (Object s : returnValue.getData()) { System.out.println(s); }`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after an extensive amount of banging my head against the wall of not understanding:

- First of all, don't programatically skip adding any values to the original series. Add all 0-values ranging between the values you want to keep. This is for sorting purposes.
- Remove all 0-values when you've finalized the adding of new data.

This is the snippet of code I've used to remove the 0-values, modify for your own purposes as you wish.

```
    ObservableList<XYChart.Series> xys = bc.getData();
    for(XYChart.Series<String,Number> series : xys) {
        ArrayList<XYChart.Data> removelist = new ArrayList<>();

        for(XYChart.Data<String,Number> data: series.getData()) {
            if(data.getYValue().equals(0)) removelist.add(data);
        }

        series.getData().removeAll(removelist);
    }
```